# Best way to keep contact information synchronized

Tags: email, sync, contacts

I have Outlook at work with a lot of my contact info.  I have Gmail contacts on my personal email account. What would the best way be to keep all of this data syncronized without any overhead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using [**EssentialPIM**](http://www.essentialpim.com/); the free version suits me fine for all my needs. The pro version syncs with with Outlook, Windows Mobile devices, Google Calendar, etc.

[image]

Comment: The comparison page ( http://www.essentialpim.com/?r=products&pr=essentialpim&prr=provsfree ) says the free version cannot sync with Outlook & Google, is this right ?

Comment: you are right, the free version doesn't sync, but i don't use any other PIMs, so i don't need sync. since it is portable, i'll have it always with me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, I'd *not* recommend third-party services like [Plaxo](http://www.shibumi.org/eoti.htm). I really fail to understand why people think it's all right to send *my* contact details to some service I never asked for...

Comment: Using Plaxo for contact management doesn't require you to send contact details around.  You can use it purely for your own contact management.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use outlook, but I find it best to keep all you contact, mail and calendar info with google and then sync up what ever desktop app you are using to gmail/google calendar. That way you don't have to worry about duplicated mail/contacts, and you also have your mail/contacts backed up should anything ever happen to your computer.